# BIRT Report Client or Server Side Filtering?

Tags: eclipse, birt

I have worked extensively to hide portions of my BIRT report and even have it integrated with Active Directory; however, I am unsure if BIRT filters the results on the server side (secure) or the client side (not secure).  I know that the SQL is executed on the server side (the JDBC drivers are not on every client).  Is the Visibility criteria applied on the server side (as I hope) or implemented in Javascript on the client?  I have searched through the generated pages which are hard to read and have found no evidence of client side filtering but I would like a definitive answer.

Comment: I can't answer this but I believe [Dominique](http://stackoverflow.com/users/824674/dominique) can, important point may be, are you filtering the data in your SQL query or in BIRT after the SQL results are returned?  It sounds like your SQL brings back all the records then you filter it in BIRT.

Comment: The results are all being returned and I am using an attribute of the data to set the visibility flag to true or false for row elements.  I am sure the SQL query brings back all the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this visibility property is filtering elements on server-side, so it is secured in your case. As far as i know there is only one BIRT property acting as a sort of client-side filter: this is the "General -> display" property (block | inline | No display).

However for performance considerations, hiding an element with "visibility" property won't prevent possible datasets attached to this element from being executed: in some situations "dropping" elements by script is a better option.

Comment: Thanks so much for your timely response!